# Deletion of a list in python with and without ':' operator

Tags: python, list, memory, garbage-collection

I've been working with python for quite a bit of time and I'm confused regarding few issues in the areas of Garbage Collection, memory management as well as the real deal with the deletion of the variables and freeing memory.

```
>>> pop = range(1000)
>>> p = pop[100:700]
>>> del pop[:]
>>> pop
[]
>>> p
[100.. ,200.. 300...699]
```

In the above piece of code, this happens. But,

```
>>> pop = range(1000)
>>> k = pop   
>>> del pop[:]
>>> pop 
[]
>>> k
[]
```

Here in the 2nd case, it implies that the k is just pointing the list 'pop'.

**First Part of the question :**

But, what's happening in the 1st code block? Is the memory containing [100:700] elements not getting deleted or is it duplicated when list 'p' is created?

**Second Part of the question :**

Also, I've tried including gc.enable and gc.collect statements in between wherever possible but there's no change in the memory utilization in both the codes. This is kind of puzzling. Isn't this bad that python is not returning free memory back to OS? Correct me if I'm wrong  in the little research I've did. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slicing a sequence results in a new sequence, with a shallow copy of the appropriate elements.

Returning the memory to the OS *might* be bad, since the script may turn around and create new objects, at which point Python would have to request the memory from the OS again.

Comment: So, is there no other way I could shrink the memory usage? Lets say I'm working with a really huge list, after a while, if I want to remove parts of the list so that other processes don't get starved/depleted of their share.

BTW, thanks for the answer. Started studying the things behind slicing. :D :D

Comment: When the OS asks for the memory back, Python will return it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How can an OS ask memory back from a process?

Answer (score 1):

1st part:

In the 1st code block, you create a new object where the elements of the old one are copied before deleting that one.

In the 2nd code block, however, you just assign a reference to the same object to another variable. Then you empty the list, which, of course, is visible via both references.

2nd part: Memory is returned when appropriate, but not always. Under the hood of Python, there is a memory allocator which has control over where the memory comes from. There are 2 ways: via the `brk()/sbrk()` mechanism (for smaller memory blocks) and via `mmap()` (larger blocks).

Here we have rather smaller blocks which get allocated directly at the end of the data segment:

```
datadatadata object1object1 object2object2
```

If we only free object1, we have a memory gap which can be reused for the next object, but cannot easily freed and returned to the OS.

If we free both objects, memory could be returned. But there probably is a threshold for keeping memory back for a while, because returning everything immediately is not the very best thing.